# emacs: is before-save-hook a local variable?

Tags: emacs, elisp

how would I figure this out?

I added `delete-trailing-whitespace` to the `before-save-hook` in my `c-mode-common-hook`, but it looks like `delete-trailing-whitespace` is getting called for every file, not just buffers using c-mode and derivatives.

Can I make the `before-save-hook` buffer local?

Comment: There's also `ws-trim`, which is what I use: ftp://ftp.lysator.liu.se/pub/emacs/ws-trim.el

Comment: Whether a hook is buffer-local or not is the wrong question: all hooks are.  The question is whether the function you added to it was added to the buffer-local part or the global part (which depends on the `local` argument you passed to `add-hook`).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add it to `write-contents-functions` instead:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda()
    (add-hook 'write-contents-functions
      (lambda()
        (save-excursion
          (delete-trailing-whitespace)))
      nil t)))
```

As the Emacs Lisp Reference Manual explains:

> This works just like write-file-functions, but it is intended for hooks that pertain to
>   the buffer's contents, not to the particular visited file or its location. Such hooks are
>   usually set up by major modes, as buffer-local bindings for this variable. This variable
>   automatically becomes buffer-local whenever it is set; switching to a new major mode
>   always resets this variable, but calling set-visited-file-name does not.

This works properly for me in Emacs 24.2.1 (i.e., it deletes all trailing whitespace from C files but preserves trailing whitespace in all other file types).

Comment: Thanks; I corrected the corresponding bug on EmacsWiki and pointed back here for credit.

Comment: (Almost) all hooks are both local and global.  Just use the `local' argument of `add-hook' to say whether you want to add your function globally or buffer-locally.  `local-write-file-hooks` is obsolete since Emacs-22.1 as is `write-file-hooks` (replaced by `write-file-functions`), so you might want to update your reference manual.

Answer (score 21):

No, the variable `before-save-hook` is not naturally buffer local. The variable's documentation does not say it's buffer local or say it will automatically become buffer local when set.

If you want to add a buffer-local hook to it, the correct way to do this is just to use the optional LOCAL parameter of the standard `add-hook` function:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'foo nil t)
```

The add-hook documentation says:

> The optional fourth argument, LOCAL, if non-nil, says to modify
>   the hook's buffer-local value rather than its global value.
>   This makes the hook buffer-local, and it makes t a member of the
>   buffer-local value.  That acts as a flag to run the hook
>   functions of the global value as well as in the local value.

The selected answer to add it to `local-write-file-hooks` is wrong, I believe. If you look at the documentation for that function, on emacs 24.3, it says the variable is obsolete since 22.1, and you should use `write-file-functions`. And if you lookup the documentation of `write-file-functions`, it describes more complex behavior and says at the end that "To perform various checks or updates before the buffer is saved, use `before-save-hook'".

Comment: There is a problem, I'd even say it's a bug regarding `LOCAL` arg. You see, calling with non-nil `LOCAL` makes it create *new empty* variable, to which it then adds your hook. That is, if you had any other hook, they will disappear in the buffer. So instead you will probably want to use `make-local-variable` and then plain `add-hook` without any additional args.

Answer (score 3):

Never wanted to do this before, but this should work:

```
(set (make-local-variable 'before-save-hook) '((lambda() (rg-msg "foobie"))))
```

In general C-h v will prompt for a variable name and display a description telling you whether the var is buffer-local.

> before-save-hook is a variable defined
>   in `files.el'. Its value is nil
>
> This variable is potentially risky
>   when used as a file local variable.
>
> Documentation: Normal hook that is run
>   before a buffer is saved to its file.
>
> You can customize this variable.

vs.

> next-error-function is a variable
>   defined in `simple.el'. Its value is
>   nil
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local
>   when set in any fashion.   This
>   variable is potentially risky when
>   used as a file local variable.
>
> Documentation: Function to use to find
>   the next error in the current buffer.
>   The function is called with 2
>   parameters:
>
> [...]

Comment: I'm not sure whether this was correct at the time it was written, but the current documentation states "Do not use `make-local-variable` to make a hook variable buffer-local. Instead, use `add-hook` and specify `t` for the LOCAL argument."

Comment: The deprecation of `make-local-variable` for hooks dates back to Emacs-21.

Answer (score 2):

Yes create a `.dir-locals.el` file in your project root directory with this contents:

```
((c-mode . ((before-save-hook . (lambda() (delete-trailing-whitespace)) )) ))
```

This will add this hook only to `c-mode` buffers below this directory.

But if you only want a specific file and not a whole directory you should be able to add this to top of file using File Local Variables:

```
-*- eval: (setq before-save-hook (lambda() (delete-trailing-whitespace))); -*-
```

or bottom of file like this:

```
;;; Local Variables: ***
;;; eval: (setq before-save-hook (lambda() (delete-trailing-whitespace))) ***
;;; End: ***
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `write-contents-function` instead:

```
write-contents-functions is a variable defined in `files.el'.
Its value is nil

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set in any fashion.

Documentation:
List of functions to be called before writing out a buffer to a file.
If one of them returns non-nil, the file is considered already written
and the rest are not called and neither are the functions in
`write-file-functions'.

This variable is meant to be used for hooks that pertain to the
buffer's contents, not to the particular visited file; thus,
`set-visited-file-name' does not clear this variable; but changing the
major mode does clear it.

For hooks that _do_ pertain to the particular visited file, use
`write-file-functions'.  Both this variable and
`write-file-functions' relate to how a buffer is saved to file.
To perform various checks or updates before the buffer is saved,
use `before-save-hook'.
```

You should create a wrapper to call `delete-trailing-whitespace` as you want to ensure that you return `nil` from the wrapper, so that further processing (and eventual saving) takes place.

Comment: Why should one use write-contents-functions instead of local-write-file-hooks?