# How to have Emacs save file at multiple locations?

Tags: emacs

Is there an easy way to have emacs save current buffer in two locations?
I could in the 'after-save-hook' programmatically copy the current file to a second location, but writing lisp code for that might take some time.

For those that are curious why I want this:
I want the changes I make to my JSP immediately be deployed in tomcat's webapps/myapp directory.

So everytime I save a JSP file I want it saved in both my current version controlled source location as well as in the directory where my Tomcat application is deployed.

I can't use symlinks because I use a windows machine and the destination location is a directory in Linux box that is exported through Samba.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the problem you are trying to solve is to deploy changes immediately, I would suggest writing a script (in your case a batch file) that invokes `rsync` with the appropriate options.  You could either run this in the `after-save-hook` (which is probably overkill) or assign a hotkey to run it for you when you have made a set of changes that you want to test.  Something like:

```
(global-set-key 'f11 (shell-command "c:/dev/deploy_to_test.bat"))
```

where the script would look like this:

```
rsync -avz --del c:/dev/mywebapp z:/srv/tomcat/mywebapp
```

This is probably better than saving the same file in multiple places, as it ensures the deployment directory always matches what you have in your source repository.

Comment: To improve on this: Rebind `C-x C-s` to perform both the normal file save and the deploy script.

Comment: I like the comment from jdmichal along with your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work:

```
(add-hook 'local-write-file-hooks 'my-save-hook)
(defun my-save-hook ()
  "write the file in two places"
  (let ((orig (buffer-file-name)))
    (write-file (concat "/some/other/path" (file-name-nondirectory orig)) nil)
    (write-file orig nil)))
```

For more on `local-write-file-hooks` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931784/emacs-is-before-save-hook-a-local-variable/1931837#1931837).

Obviously customize the file name created in the first call to `'write-file`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a more general solution is a hook similar to this Gist: https://gist.github.com/howardabrams/67d60458858f407a13bd :

```
(defun ha/folder-action-save-hook ()
  "A file save hook that will look for a script in the same directory, called .on-save.  It will then execute that script asynchronously."
  (let* ((filename (buffer-file-name))
         (dir (file-name-directory filename))
         (script (concat dir ".on-save"))
         (cmd (concat script " " filename)))
    (write-file filename nil)
    (when (file-exists-p script)
      (async-shell-command cmd))))

(add-hook 'local-write-file-hooks 'ha/folder-action-save-hook)
```

Essentially, on any file save, if the directory where the file is being saved has an executable script called `.on-save`, it will execute that script with the name of the file being saved.

This allows you to specify an `rsync` command (or one or more other commands) on a per-directory basis. Granted, this could be expanded to walk up a directory tree looking for this sort of pattern.

Comment: This script probably needs a prompt to confirm using the .on-save file in particular when the file is not owned by the invoking user.