# emacs to automatically rsync?

Tags: emacs, scripting, rsync

This was discussed in a emacs [StackExchange Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943283/how-to-have-emacs-save-file-at-multiple-locations?newreg=e6fb375b4798497181e6e21655e7a1cf) where [Howard Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324909/howard-abrams) and [gavinb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172642/gavinb) mentioned something that could work.  However, I am such a newbie to emacs, and not a programmer at all, that I have no idea of how to get his code to work in my emacs editor.  I have started to use org-mode and have used the "easy customization" mode to change things in "[-]-\ Group Org", but I don't know enough to know what to do with it to implement a complete solution.

I assume that the gist code of Mr. Abrams works to run one script named ".on-save" that lives in the same directory as the file that is being saved. And that this code runs the .on-save script and passes the saved file's name to that script to process.  At that point I get lost in how to get a rsync script to process the saved file's name.

1. Would I put the code that Mr. Abrams mentions in my ~.emacs file?
2. Alternatively do I use "easy customization" to run Mr. Abrams code?
3. If I managed to run/install the code, how would my rsync script look to make use of his code to pass the file name of the file being saved to the rsync script for processing.

Thanks.

Aaron

Comment: I won't have any free time in the foreseeable future to figure out how to implement your links; however, here is a link to my own setup using rsync **manually** just in case that may help:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5844/2287

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate it.

Comment: are you looking for this : http://cestdiego.github.io/blog/2015/12/04/using-rsync-when-tramp-is-too-much/ ?

Comment: Lompik, thanks for the reference.  That is a bit complex for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I bound Alt-F11 to trigger a shell script ".rsync-org-mode.sh".
In my .emacs file I put the following:

```
(defvar script-name "~/.rsync-org-mode.sh")

(defun call-my-script-with-word ()
(interactive)
(shell-command
(concat script-name 
       " "
       (thing-at-point 'word))))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<f11>") 'call-my-script-with-word)
```

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -avh --delete ~/My-Org-Directory/ /My-Backup-Org-Directory/
```

I saved the script as ~/.rsync-org-mode.sh and made it executable with chmod+ It rsync's my entire org-mode directory.

To use it I periodically save to backup using Alt-F11.   I did not want it to be automatic for fear that it would automatically sync a bad copy.

Very very low tech, but it is adequate for my needs, and it will sync the directories. Lawlist's solution in the post he referenced is great, and more comprehensive, but since I fuse mount my only sftp directory prior to each emacs session, it was more than I really needed.