# Emacs 24: untabify on save for everything *except* makefiles

Tags: emacs, makefile

I have the following code in my `.emacs`:

```
;; untabify on save                                                                                                                                                                                               
;; source: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UntabifyUponSave and                                                                                                                                                    
;; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318553/getting-emacs-to-untabify-when-saving-certain-file-types-and-only-those-file-ty                                                                                      
;; and a little help from http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_avoid_lambda_in_hook.html                                                                                                                              
;; and help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931784/emacs-is-before-save-hook-a-local-variable                                                                                                            
(defun untabify-everything ()
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
(defun untabify-everything-on-save ()
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'untabify-everything)
  nil)

;; I think the c-mode-common-hook includes the makefile-modes, so it's untabifying those                                                                                                                          
;; maybe not?                                                                                                                                                                                                     
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
;; (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)                                                                                                                                                           
;; (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)                                                                                                                                                         
;; (add-hook 'java-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)                                                                                                                                                        
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'untabify-everything-on-save)
```

but `untabify-everything-on-save` seems to be running for `BSDmakefile-mode` and `makefile-mode`.  How do I get it to not do that?

(I have a workaround in my `makefile` for now:

```
.RECIPEPREFIX = +
tree:
+ @tree -L 2 -C $(PROJECT_DIR)
```

but that's not a satisfying solution.  It assumes everyone who receives my makefile has GNU Make version > 3.81, which I can't guarantee.)

Comment: Be aware that if you ever work collaboratively with people under version control, this kind of brute-force approach may easily cause you to commit lots of whitespace changes unrelated to what you're actually doing, which is never a good look. Your time might be better spent ensuring that the changes *you* make will be well-formatted, without also stomping over the entire file.

Comment: Good point, but the "state religion" around here is spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following defines a function to `untabify` the entire buffer except if its major mode is `makefile-mode` or one of its derivatives.  We can put that function in the `before-save-hook` to get the functionality you're after:

```
(defun untabify-except-makefiles ()
  "Replace tabs with spaces except in makefiles."
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'makefile-mode)
    (untabify (point-min) (point-max))))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'untabify-except-makefiles)
```

Notice that the only thing that the original `untabify-everything-on-save` did was to add the original `untabify-everything` to the `before-save-hook`, so it was applied to every buffer you tried to save to file, including the make files.  Adding the original `untabify-everything-on-save` to the various mode hooks was basically calling a function to add to a hook from another hook, which did not achieve the functionality you wanted and is strange conceptually.

Comment: I realize that my question related to turning off buffer-wide untabify on saving for only one particular mode, but now that I think about it, it seems like turning it on for certain modes is better so I'm not caught by surprise were I to edit a new file type in the future.  Is there a way to make `before-save-hook` buffer local, or does the solution require much deeper tweaking than that?

Comment: It's probably overkill.  If you untabify a buffer once, it's always untabified -- no need to do it on every save.  If you stick [`(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NoTabs) in your .emacs file, Emacs will insert spaces instead of tabs.  All your buffers from here on out will be "untabified" by default, and all you have to do with your old files is untabify them once by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As per [emacs: is before-save-hook a local variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931784/emacs-is-before-save-hook-a-local-variable?lq=1), (!! I mistakenly thought) the solution was to change

```
(defun untabify-everything-on-save ()
  (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'untabify-everything)
  nil)
```

to

```
(defun untabify-everything-on-save ()
  (add-hook 'write-contents-functions 'untabify-everything)
  nil)
```

because I guess the former would infect multiple buffers, while the latter is apparently local to a particular buffer.

edit: Wait, I saved and reloaded my `.emacs` file and thought it worked, but then I restarted Emacs, and now it hangs when I try to save my `.emacs` buffer (and possibly all the other modes that invoke `untabify-everything-on-save`).

edit2: I `nano`'d my `.emacs` file to comment out the line about `untabify-everything-on-save`ing files in `emacs-lisp-mode`, so at least I can edit that file in Emacs, but it seems any of the other modes are, as expected, unable to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this as I had the same question. In the end I came up with:

```
(defun tvaughan/untabify ()
  "Preserve initial tab when 'makefile-mode."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (if (derived-mode-p 'makefile-mode)
      (progn
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (not (eobp))
          (skip-chars-forward "\t")
          (untabify (point) (line-end-position))
          (forward-line 1)))
      (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))))

(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'tvaughan/untabify)
```

I often span commands across several lines, and I like the line continuation markers to line-up. For example:

```
.PHONY: import-ova
import-ova: $(VMPACKAGE).ova
    @if ! VBoxManage list vms | grep -cq $(VMNAME);                         \
    then                                                                    \
        VBoxManage import $(VMPACKAGE).ova                                  \
          --vsys 0                                                          \
          --vmname $(VMNAME)                                                \
          --ostype Windows10_64                                             \
          --cpus 2                                                          \
          --memory 2048                                                     \
          --eula accept;                                                    \
    fi
```

Source: https://gitlab.com/tvaughan/windows-vm/blob/master/Makefile